# DraggableScrollableSheet closes when swiping up

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have noticed if `maxChildSize` and `minChildSize` has the same value then swiping up on the contents of DraggableScrollableSheet closes the bottom sheet.

The expected behaviour is to scroll down the `ListView` provided in the `builder` argument of the `DraggableScrollableSheet`.

I believe the expected behaviour should be followed even when both `maxChildSize` and `minChildSize` are the same.

Am I missing something?

Here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DraggableBottomSheetTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableBottomSheetTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              builder: (context) {
                return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  maxChildSize: 0.5,
                  minChildSize: 0.5,
                  initialChildSize: 0.5,
                  expand: false,
                  builder: (context, controller) => ListView.builder(
                    controller: controller,
                    itemCount: 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Modal BottomSheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DraggableBottomSheetTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableBottomSheetTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true, // set this to true
              builder: (context) {
                return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  maxChildSize: 0.5,
                  minChildSize: 0.5,
                  initialChildSize: 0.5,
                  expand: false,
                  builder: (context, controller) => ListView.builder(
                    controller: controller,
                    itemCount: 50,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Modal BottomSheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did adding `isScrollControlled: true` work for you? I just tested it (and updated my question) and it gives the same behaviour as before!